# OpenLayers 5 ZoomToExtent API

Tags: javascript, openlayers, zoom

I have a button with class `search_` and when clicked i want to change the map view to a specific extent. I am using [ZoomToExtend API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_ZoomToExtent-ZoomToExtent.html).

Here is what i try, without anything working:

```
   var roadlayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [roadlayer],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.ScaleLine()]),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
        zoom: 14,
        maxZoom: 19
    })
});
var layerExtent = roadlayer.getExtent();

$('.search_').on('click', function() {
    var ZoomToExtend = function() {
        map.getView().fit(layerExtent, map.getSize());
    }

    try {
        ZoomToExtend();
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }

});
```

**Errors:**

Error 1: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSimplifiedGeometry' of undefined

`roadlayer.getExtent();` is undefined. Note that it's the base layer.

**Update:**
Mike's comment helped but `getExtent()` only works for the baselayer. What should i use for the dynamically added layer below?

```
var wmsLayer_Parcel = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: NicURL,
    params: {
      'LAYERS': 'parcel_layer'
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
   // crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  })
});
```

This won't work:

```
var layerExtent = wmsLayer_Parcel.getExtent() || wmsLayer_Parcel.getSource().getTileGrid().getExtent();

var ZoomToExtent = function(){
map.getView().fit(layerExtent,{
  duration: 1600,
  nearest: true
});
```

Comment: layerExtent  is undefined?

Comment: You haven't specified and extent when you declared roadLayer.  It none is specified the entire extent of the tile grid will be available `var layerExtent = roadlayer.getExtent() || roadlayer.getSource().getTileGrid().getExtent();`

Comment: As you can see in OL5 example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html, for single image WMS you have to specify extent yourself.

Comment: @TomazicM the layers will be added dynamically depending on the input. So each layer  has different size and position. Why should i set the extent statically?

Comment: If you don't specify an extent OpenLayers will request data for anywhere covered view's projection.  If you know the WMS data has a limited extent you could find the bbox by parsing the WMS capabilities before creating the layer https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wms-capabilities.html

Comment: My question is clear : `i want to change the map view to a specific extent` so if i specify it how will it change dynamically depending on the given layer?

Comment: If you want to use the extent of the layer you will need to set the extent of each layer, just as you need set the url and LAYERS parameter.

Comment: Okay so if i specify the extent what do i need to change on the example you gave . Instead of `roadmap` I should use `wmsLayer_Parcel ` layer @Mike ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify an extent when you create the layer

```
var wmsLayer_Parcel = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: NicURL,
    params: {
      'LAYERS': 'parcel_layer'
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
   // crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  }),
  extent: ????
});
```

`wmsLayer_Parcel.getExtent()` will return that when you need to fit the layer

Comment: Alright, i thought that it should be requested from the server and get the result of the extent along with the layers.

Comment: If you know the url and layers you would most likely know or could find out the extent and code it in, but it could be found by loading and parsing the WMS capabilities if necessary, for example if an application wasn't receiving the url and layer requirements until run time.

Comment: okay i can you please show an example retrieving the extent from the XMLfile and assign that to the layer extent property?

Comment: You could either create a layer asynchronously after parsing the extent for an immediate fit https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaEJJj
or create a layer then asynchronously set the extent for use by a button https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbQPRz

Comment: used your second example, it helped but i get: Access to fetch at 'http:/...' from origin 'http://localhost:82' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: To read anything by XHR or fetch the document needs to be either same origin or CORS enabled.  For public WMS that is normal, but if you are using your own localhost you will need to enable it in the server settings.

Comment: Tried this on different geo server and i am getting 401 unauthorized. Is there any way to avoid that? I have tried to use `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` but nothing

Comment: See the Enable CORS section in https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html